# Stop the dependent packages from getting removed in yum history undo command

Tags: centos, yum, undo

I want to undo a yum installation. The packages, dependencies that were installed should be uninstalled, upgraded packages should be downgraded to the earlier version. If downgraded version not available skip removing the package.

Tried using `yum history undo <id>` but it removes the dependents of the packages that are going to be removed. How can i prevent the packages from getting removed that have dependents ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There is no single command line that can do what you want here.

Explanation:

If you have `pkg-foo` depends on `pkg-bar` and `pkg-bar` depends on `pkg-baz`, then during installation all of the above together, they will be given a single transaction id let's assume `id=10`. Then you install `pkg-goo` that depends on `pkg-baz` in a different transaction, `id=11`.

During `yum history undo 10`, it will try to erase everything that was installed during that id and because of dependencies of `pkg-baz` it will remove `pkg-goo` that was done in `id=11`.

If you don't want `pkg-goo` to be uninstalled, then it is better to use

```
yum remove pkg-foo pkg-bar
```

OR

```
yum downgrade pkg-foo pkg-bar
```

Comment: i am uninstalling a package that has 76 dependencies and 7 upgrades